# cocos2d-x connection to Windows Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, cocos2d-x

I write an application using cocos2d-x. Now I want to store some data in the Windows Azure Storage and get the data sometime, how can I do that?

Comment: You really need to narrow this down. Really hard to figure out what you're asking about. Did you build an ios app? Running in a different platform? Are you planning on connecting to storage from a client app or from a server? What type of storage are you looking at (Azure has tables, blobs, queues, SQL)?

Comment: Yes, I build an ios app. I want to store the users' name, score and so on on the server. When the app start, it can poll the data from the server.@DavidMakogon

Answer (score 0):

As written, it's difficult to answer such a broad question. Having said that: I'll do my best to give you an objective answer describing Azure's storage options from a service perspective.

- [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/). This lets you have a CRUD interface to storage, and is build to provide a REST-based API, which fronts storage. It defaults to SQL Database, but you can easily override this by creating your own custom API and using server-side JavaScript / Node.js to read/write to any storage system.
- [Azure blobs/tables/queues](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/). This is the collective set of Azure large-scale storage, with up to 200TB per account namespace. You can access storage directly from your game, or through your own service tier - that's up to you. You need to worry about security, as you don't want to have your blobs exposed as *public* unless you want to. Fortunately you may use something called a *Shared Access Signature* to grant access to your app, while keeping these resources private to the rest of the world.
- [SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/sql-database/). Azure provides database-as-a-service, largely compatible with SQL Server. As long as you have a proper connection string, it's just like having a local database.
- 3rd-party hosted solutions. There are companies that host data services in Azure, such as ClearDB (MySQL) and MongoLab (MongoDB).

One other option: Custom database solutions. If you're not using a built-in or 3rd-party storage service, you can always install a database server within a [Virtual Machine](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines/). You're now managing the server, but this would give you ultimate choice.

Comment: I use the SQL Database in the Windows Azure Storage. I build a table on it. Now we the app starts, it get the data from the table, after quit the app, the table will update. I want to know how I can do that@David Makogon